# Unwanted Glide imports

Tags: go, dependency-management, glide-golang

I am working on an App Engine app and am coming across this error running `goapp serve`:

`Failed parsing input: parser: bad import "syscall" in vendor/golang.org/x/net/icmp/message.go`

Which is apparently from Glide importing the entire `golang.org/x/net` package when I only wanted `golang.org/x/net/context`.

The import in my glide.yaml was:

```
- package: golang.org/x/net
  subpackages:
  - context
```

And the glide.lock file says

```
- name: golang.org/x/net
  version: 07b51741c1d6423d4a6abab1c49940ec09cb1aaf
  subpackages:
  - context
```

How would I keep net/icmp out of my build in `goapp serve`?

Answer (score 0):

I often had extra imports when using glide (a bit like in [issue 101](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/issues/101))

Just for testing, try re-populate your vendor folder using [`govendor`](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor/)

```
govendor list
govendor fetch +m
```

In my experience, the resulting list of dependencies is cleaner.